# nestJS Mongoose callback called after return despite async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose, async-await

I am working with a nestJS project and trying to return ids of inserted objects so they can later be used to populate the reference in a different object.

```
    try {
        await this.projectModel.insertMany(newProjects, (err, addedProjects) => {
            const addedProjectsIds = addedProjects.map(ap => {
                return ap._id;
            });
            ids = ids.concat(addedProjectsIds);
            console.log('-------1--------');
            console.log(ids);
        });
    } catch(err) {
        isSuccessful = false;
        errorMessage = err.message;
    }

    console.log('---------2--------');
    console.log(ids);
    return { success: isSuccessful, message: errorMessage, result: ids };
```

I would consistently receive an empty array added into reference ids and after some analysis identified the issue being in one block which seems to ignore the async/await syntax. In the following example, I am first getting ---2--- in the console and then ---1--- which means the ids are returned before they are populated by the insertMany callback.

Why is this happening despite using await on the mongoose method? How do I mitigate it?

Comment: You can only `await` a promise, and `insertMany` is taking a callback

Comment: @Quentin I'm not sure if the linked question is correct since `insertMany` already returns a Promise so there's nothing to promisify. It seems the issue was a bit different. Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` will not work if you rely on the callback. As far as I know, `insertMany` [returns a Promise](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany) - and that's what `await` can work with. Try with something like this:

```
const addedProjects = await this.projectModel.insertMany(newProjects);
const addedProjectsIds = addedProjects.map(ap => {
    return ap._id;
});
ids = ids.concat(addedProjectsIds);
console.log('-------1--------');
console.log(ids);
```

Comment: Thanks, looks this was it. I would assume the callback should also be awaited. All works now.